# Java Swing addTab with count

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Some swing components i have:

```
    //JList
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList(listModel);

    //JTabbedPane
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    frame.add(tabbedPane);

    //JSplitPane split
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,list , tabbedPane);
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(200);
    frame.add(splitPane);

    //JScrollPane & JTextPane to go inside the tabbed panes
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,14));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
```

When a user "Opens" a text file, it should display it on a `JList` and on the `JTextPane` inside of the `JTabbedPane`. This is what I've tried:

```
int count = tabbedPane.getTabCount(); 

//Add the selected file's name as a string to tabbedPane & listModel.
tabbedPane.addTab(file, scrollPane);
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(count); 

listModel.addElement(file);
list.setSelectedIndex(count);
```

The error I get:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Tab count: 1

I've been told to keep a reference to the original tabbed pane so that the code in an ActionListener can reference this variable and add more - but I didn't understand this (I'm new). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] when you ask a question. You have been asked to do this in previous questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.setSelectedIndex(count);
```

Java indexes are zero based. The code should be:

```
list.setSelectedIndex(count - 1);
```

> I've been told to keep a reference to the original tabbed pane

and you are still not doing that.

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
```

That is a local variable, not an instance variable. How does that code look like the code from the link I provided you with in your last question???

Local variables and instance variable are basic Java. If you don't understand these you should not be working with a GUI. Read your text book first for Java basics. Read the tutorial link I gave you. Download the working code and take the time to understand it!!!

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I have no idea what is an instance variable but because of your comments I can search for examples in google, thats my way of learning, so far happy with the progress :) still struggling, but I will try to come up with a more advance question and ask again!

Comment: `I can search for examples in google,` yes that is the way to learn. Search for something like "java instance variable" or "java local variable". Again these are basic concepts that should be covered in any Java text book. But I question why you are searching for examples. I already gave you a link to a working example. Why not start there?

Comment: Your referring to the text areas example right? I couldn't figure out which is which when it comes to tabbed panes

Comment: @bababa, I'm talking about the "TextDemo". In that example you have a JTextField. You enter text in the text field. When you hit the Enter key the ActionListener is invoked and the text from the text field is copied to the text area. It shows how to create instance variables (both the text field and text area) and how to write an ActionListener to access these variables.

Comment: So start with that code to learn the concept of creating a new tab.  Replace the text area with a JTabbedPane. Then for the ActionListener, take the text from the text field and create a new tab. Once you understand this basic concept THEN you change/restructure your current code to use the ideas you just learned.